# how to disable click to sort on yui datatable?

Tags: yui, yui-datatable

I would like to move "click heading to sort" to "double click heading to sort". So currently i'm doing it with the following two lines:

```
table.unsubscribe("theadCellClickEvent", TAG.content.table.onEventSortColumn);
table.subscribe("theadCellDblclickEvent", TAG.content.table.onEventSortColumn);
```

However, when i do this, and i click on the heading, it will take me to folder/thead-id (since by default there is a "a" tag wrapped around the heading text.

Any idea how to do it properly?

Thanks a lot!

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to stop the default click event.  Create a new event handler for the click event that simply stops bubbling the event.

```
    var stopEvent = function(oArgs) {
        var evt = oArgs.event;
        YAHOO.util.Event.stopEvent(evt);
    };

    table.unsubscribe("theadCellClickEvent", TAG.content.table.onEventSortColumn);
    table.subscribe("theadCellClickEvent", stopEvent);
    table.subscribe("theadCellDblclickEvent", TAG.content.table.onEventSortColumn);
```